# Does CitusDB support `CREATE VIEW`?

Tags: postgresql, citus

Assume we have a distributed CitusDB table named `customer_reviews`, and we try to create a view on it:

```
CREATE VIEW book_reviews AS
  (SELECT * FROM customer_reviews WHERE product_group = 'Book');
```

This appears to work. But if we run:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM book_reviews;
```

CitusDB gives the following error:

```
ERROR:  cannot plan queries that include both regular and partitioned relations
```

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to work around this by manually creating the view on all worker nodes?
2. Is there a way to make `CREATE VIEW` and `DROP VIEW` work correctly on the master node, for apps which create and destroy views automatically at runtime?

Comment: A quick update, we (Citus) have seen this question and will get a response to you soon. CREATE VIEW doesn't work as you've written it, but there's a workaround which takes a little time to write up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: View support is added to Citus with [this PR](https://github.com/citusdata/citus/pull/1024).

First of all, I created [an issue](https://github.com/citusdata/citus/issues/442) to track this. Please feel free to add your comments and feedback on that issue.

Until we implement this feature, I see two workarounds;

- Using a UDF or a PL/pgSQL function to wrap the view query instead of creating the view. I added specific examples to the GitHub issue
- Create some UDFs and PL/pgSQL functions to propagate views down to the shards on worker nodes and manipulate metadata to simulate views on the master node. I also added a prototype approach to the GitHub issue

I think what is best for you depends on your `CREATE VIEW` queries and your application stack. Could you explain your use-case and how do you plan to use views a bit more?